# Evento en ComboBox dentro de un Datagridview

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario donde existe la cabecera y el detalle de una Orden de compra.
En el Load cargo los datos del detalle en un `DataGridView` con el método `CargarDetalle()` correctamente.

Mi problema es que cuando selecciono un ítem del `ComboBox`, este evento no es reconocido inmediatamente en el método `CellValueChanged` del `DataGridView`, como si el combo no perteneciera a él y no actualiza los otros campos (`puniot` y `ptotal`)
**PERO cuando luego hago click en cualquier otra celda, SÍ lo hace...**

¿Cómo puedo generar el evento `SelectionChangeCommitted` de combo mencionado?

```
    private void CargarDetalle()
    {
        dgvDetOC.Rows.Clear();
        if (TxtId.Text.Length > 0)  // es invisible. Solo se visualiza el Codigo correaltivo
        {
            oListaOrdencompras = oOrdencompra.GetAll();
            foreach (ordencompra orden in oListaOrdencompras)
            {
                if (orden.id == Convert.ToInt32(TxtId.Text))
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (det_ordencompra item in orden.det_ordencompras)
                    {
                        dgvDetOC.Rows.Add();
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = item.id.ToString();   // col invisible
                        // En tiempo de Diseño se hacen estas dos cossas:
                        // Nombre de la celda donde está el combo: Unidad
                        // DataPropertyName: IdUnidad
                        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CmbDetalle = dgvDetOC.Columns["Articulo"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
                        CmbDetalle.DataSource = oOrdenarArticulos;
                        CmbDetalle.DisplayMember = "nombre";
                        CmbDetalle.ValueMember = "id";
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = item.idarticulo;
                        //
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = item.punit;
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = item.cantidad;
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = item.ptotal;
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = item.idordencompra.ToString();    // col invisible
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



private void dgvDetOC_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvDetOC.RowCount > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Al cambiar el Articulo en el combo
                    if (dgvDetOC.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Articulo")
                    {
                        int IdArtic = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
                        articulo eArticulo = new articulo();
                        eArticulo = oArticulo.GetById(IdArtic);
                        if (eArticulo != null)
                        {
                            // Calculamos el nuevo punit y ptotal ---- ptotal = punit * cantidad
                            // Aqui la cantidad no varía
                            dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value = eArticulo.pbruto;    // punit
                            dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);   // ptotal
                            //dgvDetOC.CurrentCell = dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];
                            //DtpFechaEmision.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                    // P.Unit o Cantidad
                    if (dgvDetOC.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "punit" || dgvDetOC.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "cantidad")
                    {
                        // ptotal = punit * cantidad
                        dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(dgvDetOC.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
                    }
                    // Totalizamos los montos de la OC
                    decimal TotalOrden = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= dgvDetOC.RowCount - 1; i++)
                    {
                        TotalOrden = TotalOrden + Convert.ToDecimal(dgvDetOC.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);  // ptotal
                    }
                    TxtVventa.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", TotalOrden / (1 + Convert.ToDecimal(TxtPorcIgv.Text)));
                    TxtMtoIgv.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", TotalOrden - Convert.ToDecimal(TxtVventa.Text));
                    TxtMonto.Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", TotalOrden);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ingreso de Ítems", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: El metodo de abajo ya no se copíó con el formato correcto...

Comment: ¿Qué finalidad tiene `dgvDetOC`?, no veo cómo le asignas el evento `CellValueChanged` al `dgvDetOC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El tema es que la celda se pone en edicion y hasta que no lo quitas no da por terminadala operacion sobre la celda por eso no lanza el `CellValueChanged`

aqui

[[DataGridView] - ComboBox y evento SelectedIndexChanged](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/03/datagridview-parte-6-combobox-y-evento.html)

explico esto mismo y como usar el `EditingControlShowing` para asociar el `SelectedIndexChanged` del control ComboBox contenido dentro de la celda

Veras como usar

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl dgvCombo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;  

    if (dgvCombo != null)            
    {   
        //
        // se remueve el handler previo que pudiera tener asociado, a causa ediciones previas de la celda
        // evitando asi que se ejecuten varias veces el evento
        //
        dgvCombo.SelectedIndexChanged -= new  EventHandler(dvgCombo_SelectedIndexChanged);                

        dgvCombo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dvgCombo_SelectedIndexChanged);            
    }

}

private void dvgCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //codigo
}
```

de esta fotma tendras el evento cuando vayas cambiando la opcion del combo

La asignacion de eventos se realiza por medio del += como se explica aqui

[Cómo: Suscribir y cancelar la suscripción a eventos (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms366768.aspx)

Comment: Hola Leandro: para que se usan los operadores  -=  y  +=   ? Gracias

Comment: se usan para asignar los eventos, edite la pregunta y agregue un link que explica sobre el tema

Comment: Gracias Leandro !

Comment: recuerda marcar la respuesta si resolvio el problema

Comment: private void dvgCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int IdArtic = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetOC.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value);
        }      // El problema es que el IdArtic es el valor del ID del articulo que había y no del Nuevo que selecciono....Cómo puedo hacer para capturar el Id del articulo que selecciono en el Combo ?